# How do I parse this JSON return value in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, json

I am returning a JSON array to my jQuery function script, but cannot seem to get the syntax correct -- even after reading about a dozen different examples here.

Here is the calling jQuery ajax function:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "fetchAlleles.php",
    datatype: 'json',
    data: {'mndx': mndx, 'sndx': sndx },
    success: function(rtnval) {
      alert("success: allele_1="+rtnval['allele_1']+", allele_2="+rtnval['allele_2']);
      //alert(rtnval);
    },
    error: function() { alert('Error!'); }
    });
```

Here is the PHP code that returns the values:

```
echo "{";
echo "allele_1: ", json_encode($ary[0]), "\n";
echo "allele_2: ", json_encode($ary[1]), "\n";
echo "run_date: ", json_encode($ary[2]), "\n";
echo "}";
```

If I use my alert debugging statement, I can see what's being returned is what I expect:

```
{allele_1: "440"
allele_2: "480"
run_date: null
}
```

but anything else I try to read the values inside the JSON object comes back "undefined", whether it's

```
alert("success: allele_1="+rtnval['allele_1']+", allele_2="+rtnval['allele_2']);
```

or

```
alert("success: allele_1="+rtnval.allele_1+", allele_2="+rtnval.allele_2);
```

or

```
alert("success: allele_1="+rtnval['allele_1'][0]+", allele_2="+rtnval['allele_2'][0]);
```

Hope someone can help -- this is exasperating! (Wish JSON syntax were more obvious!)

thanks much,
rixter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery.parseJSON to make this easier http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Here's their example:

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON('{"name":"John"}');
alert( obj.name ); //John
```

Answer (score 3):

Your JSON content doesn't appear to be valid JSON - you should have quotes around the field names like

```
{ "allele_1": "value", ... }
```

Comment: more important, it's missing the comma's :)

Answer (score 2):

If you make `datatype` -> `dataType` your json will be parsed by jQuery.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "fetchAlleles.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {'mndx': mndx, 'sndx': sndx },
    success: function(rtnval) {
      alert("success: allele_1="+rtnval['allele_1']+", allele_2="+rtnval['allele_2']);
      //alert(rtnval);
    },
    error: function() { alert('Error!'); }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The PHP json output is invalid because it does not contain commas.

Change php output to:

```
echo json_encode(array(
    'allele_1' => $ary[0],
    'allele_2' => $ary[1],
    'run_date' => $ary[2]
));
```

Answer (score 1):

use `JSON.parse(rtnVal)` this function is available in all latest browsers and converts string to JSON

Answer (score 1):

Ok so there are two things I want to suggest to you.

First of all. When you are returning your values from PHP back to JavaSctipt, you'll only need to perform one `json_encode()` command. Simply build your data in a regular PHP array (yes, it can be nested arrays).

Just execute one `echo json_encode($data)` at the end of your script.

Secondly, you'll want to access that data with JavaSctipt using dot syntax if you are dealing with an object. You can use the square brackets (key) syntax when dealing with an array.

- `{ 'key1':'value1' }`
  Here you would use `data.key` to get `value1`
- `{ 'key1':[ 'array_value1', 'array_value2', ... ] }`
  Here you would use `data.key1[1]` to get `array_value2`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, like others have mentioned, your JSON is not valid.
It should be something like:

```
{
"allele_1": "440",
"allele_2": "480",
"run_date": null
}
```

if you're not sure about your json, try using something like [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/), it checks it for you.

The way you are using json_encode() in php also seems a bit odd. It would be better to put everything in a single array and json_encode the entire array once. You could recreate your json result by structuring your array in php like this:

```
$json_output = array(
    'allele_1' => '440',
    'allele_2' => '480',
    'run_date' => null
);

echo $json_output;
```

And last, the way you're accessing your $.ajax response is incorrect, you're accessing the data like it's an array, but it's an object.

```
success: function(rtnval) {
    alert("success: allele_1="+rtnval.allele_1+", allele_2="+rtnval.allele_2);
}
```

Try it like that.

Comment: Thanks; this was helpful. But the "new array" in PHP should just be "array". Plus, the object notation only worked when I ran it through jQuery.parseJSON()...see below...but thanks again. --rixter

Comment: You're welcome, you are right about "new array" I've made an edit, I make this mistake a lot when it comes to PHP, thanks for the notice :) I thought that JQuery would take care of the parsing of the json itself when you entered 'json' as the datatype, and now I see why this didn't worked out for you. It's because you've entered 'datatype' and it should have been 'dataType' you've missed the capital T, so the parseJSON() step would not have been necessary, like Kevin B already mentioned.